# Getting 'undefined is not a function' when requesting JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having issues when requesting data from a PHP file.

When I call the variable `msg[0}` I am told it is undefined but it should have been populated in the JSON request. The JS is below and you can find the PHP output at the link:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://bluecode.org.uk/intranet/otd/index.php",
        dataType: "json"
      })
     .done(function (msg) {
      console.log(msg[0])
    });
```

The actual PHP is:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO uniquedownload (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}',      'hello.html', '".(time()+(60*60*24*5))."')");

$a = array($strKey);
echo json_encode($a);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `json_encode` in the PHP script?

Comment: Yes. This is then echoed by the script

Comment: Please show the PHP script responsible for returning the JSON.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO uniquedownload (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', 'hello.html', '".(time()+(60*60*24*5))."')");

$a = array($strKey);

echo json_encode($a);

Comment: As @Ian MacIntosh has told you, you should use `console.log (msg)` to see what type of object you back. Once you're done, if you do not find the way to access the data, publishes the results of the log and we try to help you.

Comment: I fixed it. I didn't have the PHP Json header... Thanks for your help :_

Comment: Put the solution in a new answer and mark it as correct. This is useful for making the solution easy to find for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this to the PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend logging msg so you can see how the data looks, and maybe adding a `debugger;` into your `.done()` callback to give yourself a way of experimenting with different ways of accessing the properties of `msg`.